# Make "#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex" also exported to html (orgmode)

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, html

I know that placing `latex` code in the main text body solve my issue: the `latex` code is taken into account both when exporting to `latex` and to `html`. However, I like to use Latex blocks because of the syntax highlighting (usefull for long equations etc.).

Does anyone knows a way to make this block also treated by MathJax when exported throught `org-export`:

```latex
#+begin_export latex
\begin{equation}
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \dfrac{\partial C(x, t)}{\partial t} = \vec{\nabla} \cdot \left( D(x)\vec{\nabla} C(x,t) \right) 
        \quad \forall x\in\Omega \\
        \dfrac{\partial C(x)}{\partial \vec{n}} = 0  
        \quad \forall x\in\partial\Omega \\
        C(x, t=0) = C_{init}(x)
    \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
#+end_export
```

Comment: I don't know of a simple way. You may be able to write a function that deletes the `#+begin/end_export` lines and add it to either `org-export-before-processing-hook` or `org-export-before-parsing-hook` but I have not tried it, so no guarantees.

Comment: Can't you just get rid of the #+begin/end_export blocks so it works for both? If syntax highlighting is all you want, I think you just (setq org-highlight-latex-and-related t).

Comment: Good catch about the variable, but I think something like this is needed: `(setq org-highlight-latex-and-related '(native))` per the doc (and I had to revert the buffer to get it to show).

Comment: Well, it does not work for me... thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: This sounds like something you might want: https://alhassy.github.io/org-special-block-extras/